# Can we create a Public Facebook BOT without pages_messaging permission?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

As per the Facebook Graph API

> You can create, access and delete test user accounts in a couple of ways - by using the Graph API to do it programmatically, or by using the App Dashboard to do it manually.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users

The application can be made public and will be visible in messenger.

Which means who ever tries to say "hi" to a BOT which will come to the webhook, what if I automatically add all of them as test users.

Doesn't this overrides the rules of Facebook Photo ID proof verification?

Does this means that I can create a public Facebook BOT without using pages_messaging permission?

Comment: No one will be able to say "hi" to your bot, if you don’t have a proper bot set up first.

Comment: I can prove it, If I subscribe a webhook and page and make the app public anyone can say hi to the bot and making app public will happen immediately in matter of no time

Comment: So you have a bot that users can send a message to, but the bot can’t reply (because it doesn’t have the permission approved)? _Possible_ that you can wriggle your way around having to submit it the way you described - but it should be obvious Facebook does not want you to do this, so don’t be surprised if you simply get your app blocked when they find out. Plus, the number of tester you can add to an app might be limited.

Comment: I am not going to do it, because I know the consequences, but I thought of bringing this topic to confirm, the number max test users seems 500, as you told it is limited